# Visual studio 2022 javascript debug enabled not working with chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome, debugging

Using visual studio 2022 V17.5.2

when i disable javascript debugging, chrome works fine,
but when i enable javascript debug, chrome doesn't launch the site, it just stays loading

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkrOb.png)

Comment: Hello, there are many reasons for this phenomenon? Before giving the solution, I would like to ask, if you use Microsoft Edge browser, will this happen?

Comment: only with chrome and only with a project

Comment: In Visual Studio, there is a drop-down bar on the left side of running your project => Debug Properties => IIS Express => IIS Express bitness => choose x86 or x64 according to your own situation. If it still doesn't work, please update VS to the latest version. On the other hand, this may not be the reason of VS, you can report to Chrome official.